# Conversion String to Double is not valid in VB

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem with try and catch in VB. I have 2 buttons(btnCalculate,btnPay) and 3 labels(lblTotal, lblCash, lblChange)
btnCalculate = total the price 
btnPay = amount paid by customer

lblTotal = display the total price
lblCash = display cash paid by customer
lblChange = display the change

**EDIT:Conversion from string to type Double is not valid error**

```
Private Sub btnPay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPay.Click
    Dim payAmount As Double
    Dim total As Double
    total = CDbl(lblTotal.Text)

    Do While (payAmount < total)
        payAmount = Val(InputBox("Enter customer pay amount: "))
        If (payAmount < total) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please pay the amount of total bill!")
        Else
            lblCash.Text = "$" & CStr(payAmount)
            lblChange.Text = "$" & CStr(payAmount - total)
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: This is very broken exception reporting, it is a "it didn't work" message without telling anybody *why* it didn't work.  So you don't know why it doesn't work and cannot know how to fix it.  *Never* hide the reason for the exception.

Comment: `payAmount - lblTotal.Text` - Please use [Option Strict On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: I just message out the error, it shows that my lblTotal.Text value to type Double is not valid. 
@TheBlueDog i just turned it on and it still has the same problem

Comment: I guess you'd better find out why then. Option Strict doesn't magically fix problems for you, it just prevents you trying to do something you shouldn't be doing in the first place. [HINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I'll go one better and advise you to **remove the try catch**, let the program crash so you know where the problem is so they can be fixed.  Converting text boxes to numerics do not need Try/Catch and Try/Catch is **not** data validation.

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks for your advise! I got it.I'm struggling with this error.

Comment: What does `lblTotal.text` have when the exception is thrown?

Comment: @JoshPart I just removed the try and catch and it is not necessary to add it as plutonix mentioned above. But i still have an error for total = CDbl(lblTotal.Text) of String convert to double is not valid.

Comment: what *exactly* is in the label when it fails?  Also what country are you in?

Comment: Look, it's quite simple - either `lblTotal.Text` is an empty string or it contains characters that cannot be parsed to a number.

Comment: @TheBlueDog yeah, it contains of "$". How do I exclude this sign?

Comment: are you in the US or CAN? (it is not a frivolous question!)  France, for instance, does nto know "$" from a croissant.

Comment: At last. Remove it from the text field altogether and add it as a separate label on the form or something.

Comment: @Plutonix I'm not from that both of the country. I just curious on why my friend got the error when compile the code above but I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: well, if your country doesn't use Dollars, dont show dollar signs.  It is wrong anyway to glue "$" to CSTR - it should be `payamount.ToString("C2")` and the vars should probably be Decimal.  Using the local currency symbol will allow the code to work (somewhat).  Decimal.Parse would be better than CDbl/CDec

Comment: @Plutonix It is just for my individual learning purposes and not for business object because I'm just new in VB. I will try it after that. Thanks for your ideas:)

Comment: **It doesnt matter** - if your computer doesnt use US notations like "$" values containing it will look invalid.  That is how CDBL and Decimal.Parse know to parse the different currency symbols: they know the local Culture.  If it is for `learning purposes`, all the more reason to learn to do it correctly.

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks for your suggestion, I mean I will do it once I solve that problem. `The Blue Dog` just mentioned where my problem is and FINALLY to solve this problem. Thank you very much! =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you *throw away the real error cause*. Look at what your program does:

- An invalid number is entered: **Please enter valid number!** is shown.
- The system is out of memory: **Please enter valid number!** is shown.
- You made a programming mistake: **Please enter valid number!** is shown.
- Something else went wrong: **Please enter valid number!** is shown.

That's not good, is it? In fact, you only want to show "Please enter a valid numer" when an invalid number has been entered, so **don't do Pokemon exception handling**: Put your exception handling *around the statement where you expect the error to occur* and *catch only the specific exception that you need*.

If you do *global* exception handling, include `ex.Message` in the error message you show to ensure that the *real* cause of the error can be determined.